# Satang api private http requeat

Tags: java, http, request, private

I'm going to use satang api with java.
This is reference book.
https://docs.satang.pro/authentication

I've completed public request code with java.

```
private String publicOperation(String operation) throws IOException, BadResponseException {

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    //URL url_ = new URL("https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");

    //https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb
    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Who can make private http request with any program language?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public String placeLimitOrder(String amount,String pair,String price,String side) throws IOException, BadResponseException
{
    Long lnonce=new Date().getTime();
    String nonce=lnonce.toString();
    String req="amount="+amount+"&nonce="+nonce+"&pair="+pair+"&price="+price+"&side="+side+"&type=limit";
    String operation="orders/";
    String signature=getSignature(req);
    URL url = new URL(baseUrl+operation);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("POST");
    con.setDoOutput( true );
    con.setInstanceFollowRedirects( false );

    con.setRequestProperty("Authorization", "TDAX-API "+this.key);
    con.setRequestProperty("Signature",signature);
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json"); 
    con.setRequestProperty("charset", "utf-8");
    con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "java client");
    con.setUseCaches( false );

    JsonObject obj=new JsonObject();
    obj.addProperty("amount", amount);
    obj.addProperty("nonce", nonce);
    obj.addProperty("pair", pair);
    obj.addProperty("price", price);
    obj.addProperty("side", side);
    obj.addProperty("type", "limit");
    String json=obj.toString();

    DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(con.getOutputStream());
    wr.writeBytes(json);
    wr.flush();
    wr.close();

    int responseCode=con.getResponseCode();

    if(responseCode!=HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK){
        throw new BadResponseException(responseCode);
    }
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));

    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
    String line;
    while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        result.append(line);
    }
    rd.close();
    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've checked. Please use this code with your satang api key. then maybe working well.

Answer (score 3):

I have the same problem
But I use google sheet to import

```
function satang(){
  var rows=[],obj_array=null;
  try {obj_array=JSON.parse(UrlFetchApp.fetch("https://api.tdax.com/api/orders/?pair=btc_thb").getContentText());} catch (e) {obj_array=null;}
  if (obj_array!=null){
    for (r in obj_array) {rows.push([parseFloat(obj_array[r].bid),parseFloat(obj_array[r].price),parseFloat(obj_array[r].amount),parseFloat(obj_array[r].ask)]);}
    var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(),sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Satang');ss.getRange("Satang!A1").setValue(new Date());
    try {var range=sheet.getRange(2,1,sheet.getLastRow(),6).clearContent();} catch(e) {Logger.log("error");}
    if (rows==null||rows=="") {Browser.msgBox("Oops, no data from satang. Please try again"); return false;}
    range=sheet.getRange(2,1,rows.length,4); range.setValues(rows); 
  }
}
```

Comment: You did'nt use private satang api?